# Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming E-Mail

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have service "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming E-Mail" in server number 2 (Central Administration > System Settings > Services on Server ), but by server number 1 is not set.

How to set this service?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

can you make a screenshot of your server number 1 and the services of it. Some services depends on other services.

Comment: I attached screenshot

Answer (score 0):

there could be two reasons that it doesn't show. First, you didn't install the SMTP Service on that machine. 2nd, UAC is enabled on this server and not server 2.

Btw, you can only use one server for incoming e-mail. The 2nd can't be used.

Comment: SMTP is install, but Admin deleted this job and I do not know how to re-set one!